# Unterminated quoted string at or near \"'\\' ORDER BY \"id\"\"" when using loopback connected to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, primary-key, loopback

When I using like filter in loopback restful api, it return the following error.

```
"name":"error","status":500,"message":"unterminated quoted string at or near \"'\\' ORDER BY \"id\"\""
```

However, when I remove the primary key setting in postgresql, the error is gone.
Does it mean that the primary key causes this error?

Comment: Show the entire query.

Comment: filter[description][like]=%123%

Comment: It's not a complete postgresql query.